# data is not saving into database using cakephp 2.0

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-model

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. i am sending data from to my controller using Ajax Post but data did not saving into the database??

**Form and Ajax**

```
$('body').on('submit','.contact_form', function () {
var action = $(this).attr('action');
var postdata = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: action,
 data: postdata,
 dataType:"html",

 success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
 },

 error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert(textStatus);
 }
 });
 return false;  

 });
 });

<?php echo $form->create('Listingbookmark',array('action'=>'add/','class'=>'contact_form'));?>
<input type="hidden" name="listingid" value="<?php echo $listingData['Listing']['id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="userid"    value="<?php echo $user_id ?>">

<input type="submit" value="Bookmark">
<?php echo $form->end(); ?>
```

**Model**

```
class Listingbookmark extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Listingbookmark';
    var $useTable = 'listingbookmark';
    var $order = array('Listingbookmark.id asc');   
}
```

**Controller Function**

```
function add()
{

$this->request->data['Listingbookmark']['listingid'] = $_POST['listingid'];
$this->request->data['Listingbookmark']['userid'] = $_POST['userid']; = $_POST['listingid'];
$this->Listingbookmark->create();
$this->Listingbookmark->save($this->request->data);

}
```

when i try to `echo` both variables it is showing values but did not saving in database

```
echo $this->request->data['Listingbookmark']['listingid'] =   $_POST['listingid'];
echo $this->request->data['Listingbookmark']['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];
$this->Listingbookmark->create();
$this->Listingbookmark->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: Is the data making it to the controller? What are the contents of `$this->data` in your `add` action?

Comment: @bill `data` is default function to storing data into the database ??

Comment: @bill so what is the other solution to store data using ajax?

Comment: Try using `$this->request->data` instead.  So `$this->Listingbookmark->saveAll($this->request->data);`  Then you can set anything you need in the js in the `$this->data` array to use in your ajax `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->data['Listingbookmark']['userid'] = $_POST['listingid'];  ?????
```

why you are using saveAll method of cakephp to insert data into table if you needs to insert data in only one table. use cakephp's save() method instead of saveAll() method.

Comment: i did this but still not saving `$this->Listingbookmark->save($this->data);`

Comment: check your array format in controller before save() method. it should be like this     Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
    (
        [fieldname1] => 'value'
        [fieldname2] => 'value'
    )
)